# What makes apk updates take so long?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

When I post an update of my app to the android market it takes hours to become available. Some times half a day why is this?

This happens even if it is just a one changed in the code or xml.

Comment: Your updates are likely either processed in the order they are recieved and/or has a human element to the process if its not entirely automatic.

Comment: This question is inappropriate for SO, partly because any answer people can provide is nothing more than speculation. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: @mah: I do not believe that this is a #dontask question because it is very possible that google has said somewhere what it is that they do. While I did search a bunch for the answer I did not find it but considering the new way searches work personalizing your search based on Bla Bla Bla I think it is very possible that someone else could find it where I could not.

Comment: @Eforen if Google has made a statement that addresses the topic then an answer would not be open ended, however it would still not be on topic for SO because the question is not about programming. http://android.stackexchange.com/ might be an appropriate place to ask but I am not certain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the sheer number of apps that are uploaded to the Android Market per day. I bet most of the process is automated but they must scan the app for malware etc, and as Ramhound said, there is probably a human element to the process as well.

**Count yourself lucky. The iOS App Store processing line is 10 + days minimum wait, but that's much more human oriented.**

Comment: There really isn't any evidence to say to prove Apple uses more human evaluation on updates to applications, there are pleanty of examples of hidden features, being added to applications actually now allowed by Apple.  Apple does have more human evaluation on the intial submission that has been proven.

Answer (score 1):

To be exact, only Google knows. But at least Googles [bouncer](http://googlemobile.blogspot.dk/2012/02/android-and-security.html) needs to test your app for any malicious content. It will also take some time before everything is updated on their servers as they should be updated in a managed fashion. Also I've noticed that apps can be browsed on the web much sooner than they arrives on mobile. Besides that I don't know what slows down the process. I would believe the process being completely automatic.